# Web API help page

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created an empty WebAPI project and added a controller with one POST method.

I have installed ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Help Page package to help the consumers of this Web API.
How or where is the help page created?
How do I access this help web page.

Comment: Consider using Swagger for web api documentation, you can check my post here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Help page is created in the folder called "Areas". Inside the file HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs there is a route defined such as the following -

```
            context.MapRoute(
            "HelpPage_Default",
            "api/Help/{action}/{apiId}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This tells how to navigate to the help page. The definition above states that the help page resides at - http://*baseurl*/api/help

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's in the path: ~/Areas/HelpPage/*.*